# How to use the totient function in the context of clocks?

Tags: totient-function

I've been tasked with finding what indication a clock has $7^{19}$ hours after 1:00AM.

I've found  $\phi (24) =8$. How do I use this to find the answer to my question?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Hint: [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) states that if $a$ and $n$ are coprime, then $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$. Since $7$ and $24$ are coprime, we have $7^8 \equiv 1 \mod 24$.
Hence, $7^{16} \equiv 1 \mod 24$, so $7^{19} \equiv 7^3 \mod 24$.

Edit: We also have $7^2 \equiv 49 \equiv 1 \mod 24$ just by simple computation.

Comment: In fact, $a^2\equiv1\bmod24$ for all $a$ relatively prime to $24$